# autoschema (drf_spectacular) for one route - building with mistake and I can't create independently this route too

Tags: routes, swagger, drf-spectacular

I use drf_spectacular and all routes building normally besides one:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
def unique_cities(self, request):
    """Getting unique cities from DB sports_person."""
    unique_cities = SportsPerson.objects.values_list('city', flat=True)
    return Response({'unique_cities': list(unique_cities)})
```

of cause, in answer I have:

```
{
    "unique_cities": [
        "New-York",  
        "Kyiv",
       "Test"
    ]
}
```

but in swagger for this route I see a schema like a general route for my person:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "first_name": "string",
    "last_name": "string",
    "birth_day": "2023-09-13",
    "rank": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "team": "string"
}
```

I understood that schema building from my serializer for my CRUD endpoints, but for problems route I don't need them. I tried to use than thing like:

```
@extend_schema(
    responses={200: {"unique_cities": [str]}},
    examples={
        "application/json": {
            "unique_cities": ["New-York", "Kyiv", "Test"]
        }
    },
)
```

but do not work too
I see two way for solved this problem: implement correct @extend_schema or fix work autoschema from drf_spectacular, but i'm stuck and can't find a solution

Comment: If only I add "examples=" the page /api/docs/ give error:"Fetch error
Internal Server Error /api/schema/"

Answer (score 0):

the problem, that @detail_route() no more used but @action() no opened for autoschema. Route is so easy that create serializers and other code is not interesting, that I decide make a schema in decorator. It works completely

```
@extend_schema(
    parameters=[
        OpenApiParameter(
            name='team',
            location=OpenApiParameter.QUERY,
            description='route for fast enter name of exists team',
            required=True,
            type=str
        ),
    ],
    responses={
        200: OpenApiTypes.OBJECT,
    },
    examples=[
        OpenApiExample(
            name="Auto complete field for name team with answer",
            # summary="How the company details are returned",
            description="answer for query='jun' ",
            value={
                "auto_complete_teams": ["Junior", "Jungle"],
            },
            response_only=True
        ),
        OpenApiExample(
            name="empty answer",
            summary="Auto complete field for name team without answer",
            description="answer for query='abc' ",
            value={
                "auto_complete_teams": [],
            },
            response_only=True
        )
    ],
)
@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
def auto_complete_teams(self, request):
    """Getting relevant teams from search_key"""
    query = request.GET.get('team', '')
    relevant_teams_list = []
    if query:
        relevant_teams = SportsPerson.objects.filter(
            team__icontains=query
        )
        for relevant_team in relevant_teams:
            relevant_teams_list.append(relevant_team.team)
    return Response(
        {'auto_complete_teams': list(set(relevant_teams_list))},
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK
    )
def namefunc():
    """..."""
```